# MS Graph API without logging in

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, entra

When our application uploads files to a users OneDrive using the Microsoft Graph API we don't want the user to login each time.

Does the user still need to login to identify themselves once, and get a token they can be used in subsequent calls?

Ideally this token would last months.

Cheers Tom

Comment: The app can request a refresh token. This can be used to request new access tokens without user interactions.

Comment: Yes, the user still needs to login to identify themselves once and get an access token that can be used in subsequent calls. The access token obtained through the authentication process has an expiration time, which can be set to last for months. However, it is not recommended to have long-lived access tokens as they pose a security risk. Instead, it is recommended to use refresh tokens to obtain new access tokens when the old ones expire.

Comment: References:

-   [Authorization and sign-in for OneDrive in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#authorization-and-sign-in-for-onedrive-in-microsoft-graph)
-   [Authorizing your app to access OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/authentication?view=odsp-graph-online#authorizing-your-app-to-access-onedrive)

Comment: Cheers guys I'll check these out.

Comment: Thank you Arko those links really helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app can use a refresh token to get new tokens: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/refresh-tokens.
Unless your app is a single-page-app, the refresh token is quite long-lasting.
When you request for new tokens, you also get back a new refresh token, and you should overwrite the one you had with the new one to keep it from expiring.

Do note that this token acquisition can fail; refresh tokens can be revoked.
In that case you would need to prompt the user to log in.